# EBS - do I need to pay for storage that I dont use?

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

When I create an EBS storage, If I allocate the size to be 500GB but only end up using 30GB do I need pay for the full 500GB or do I pay for 30GB, because this is what i've used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reserved 500GB - that's what you paid for.

Comment: EBS snapshots only charge you for the data used, the drives charge you for the reserved size.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? the drives charges you for the reserved size?